# Passing a String to the name of an object

Tags: string, object

If I have a variable,

```
String teamName;
```

And I am creating an object, ie.

```
Thread teamName = new Thread(new cheerLoop());
```

Can I create a Thread name based on what is contained in the teamName variable? I am trying to run a loop that will create threads based upon the inputted name. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument of the `Thread` constructor can be a name, so

```
Thread t = new Thread(new cheerLoop(), teamName);
```

[Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.String%29)

Note that a thread's name is a property of the thread object and not the same thing as the name of a variable.  If you are interested in making a variable with a name known only at run time then you can use a more dynamic language, or, if you are using Java, store the objects in a hash map indexed by names, or use the `Thread.name` property.

(Aside: It's a little unusual to create threads directly these days; we tend to use pools and executor services and such things, just FYI.  [This S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227040/how-to-give-name-to-a-callable-thread) might have information for you on how to do this with thread pools.)

Comment: thanks buddy. and thanks for the tips at the end. i had to write this program for a data structures class.

Comment: Oh of course, being in a class explains it.  There are benefits to understanding the `Thread` class.  Then yeah you'd use the higher level services later.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't think this is the possible in any OOP language. You might wanna look this topic on Stack Overflow:
[Creating a variable name using a String value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631935/creating-a-variable-name-using-a-string-value)