# Change name or Title of javafx.concurrent.Task

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Is it possible to change/set name or title of **javafx.concurrent.Task** just like in Thread **thread.setName("name")** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing you haven't understood the concept of `javafx.concurrent.Task`

`Task` and `Threads` have the same difference, as a `Runnable` and `Thread` has.

**Can you name a `Runnable` object ?**

Still confused ? Explanation on the background..

***From the Docs***

```
public abstract class Task<V>
    extends java.util.concurrent.FutureTask<V>
                   implements Worker<V>, EventTarget
```

**FutureTask**

> A FutureTask can be used to wrap a Callable or Runnable object.
>   Because FutureTask implements Runnable, a FutureTask can be submitted
>   to an Executor for execution.

**Task**

> Likewise, since Task extends from FutureTask, it is very easy and
>   natural to use a Task with the java concurrency Executor API. Since a
>   Task is Runnable, you can also call it directly (by invoking the
>   FutureTask.run() method) from another background thread. This allows
>   for composition of work, or pass it to a new Thread constructed and
>   executed manually.

So basically you will need a `Thread` or `Executor` to execute your `Task` and I hope you already know how to name a `Thread` or `Threads spawned from Executors` ;)

*If not ..*

- [Naming your thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setName%28java.lang.String%29)
- [Naming Executor Threads - 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113746/naming-threads-and-thread-pools-of-executorservice)
- [Naming Executor Threads - 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227040/how-to-give-name-to-a-callable-thread)

Answer (score 3):

`javafx.concurrent.Task` has a title property which you can update from within the Task with the protected method `updateTitle(String newTitle)`.

In response to Edv Beq's comment:
from the [docs|https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#updateTitle-java.lang.String-]:

> updateTitle protected void updateTitle(String title)
>
> Updates the title
>   property. Calls to updateTitle are coalesced and run later on the FX
>   application thread, so calls to updateTitle, even from the FX
>   Application thread, may not necessarily result in immediate updates to
>   this property, and intermediate title values may be coalesced to save
>   on event notifications.
>
> This method is safe to be called from any thread.

My hunch would be that the title update is being queued to the jfx thread, but you are trying to access it immediately, and not getting the result you expect.  I know this wasn't the example you asked for, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Can you please show an example? I am calling "updateTitle("someTitle")" from withing the Task such as in the "succeeded()" method but when I try to print "t.getTitle().toString()" or "t.titleProperty().getValue()" - I don't get anything. This is after running the task.

Comment: my reply to @EdvBeq was too long so I added it to my answer

Comment: I called updateTitle("title") from inside the @Override call of the Task and it worked great. Thank you Jonathan.